# Download Pubmed Abstracts in Java

Tags: java, pubmed

Does anyone have an implementation of a program that downloads pubmed abstracts with title, author, date, and content to separate plaintext files given a MESH term?

Comment: This thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209076/spring-resttemplate-works-for-string-but-not-for-my-class can possibly help build a solution using Spring WebClient. Here's an example : https://github.com/VaidhyaMegha/vaidhyamegha-knowledge-graphs/blob/main/src/main/java/com/vaidhyamegha/data_cloud/kg/EntrezClient.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/soap/v2.0/DOC/esoap_java_help.html has an example. It worked for me like a charm.

I posted the code as a maven project on [github](https://github.com/renaud/pubmed_ws_client)

Comment: Link cited above is now broken.

Comment: @sandeepkunkunuru could you find a new one?

Comment: no, instead I got entrez REST API  hits : more here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209076/spring-resttemplate-works-for-string-but-not-for-my-class which  can help build a solution using Spring WebClient

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in function for downloading different type of files (for example XML, CSV, and plain text files) right on the PubMed homepage. Just make a search and then select "Send to" where you'll be given a plethora of options.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to esoap you can also use [RESTful API](http://europepmc.org/RestfulWebService).

Assuming that you want to get all articles with `MESH keyword: galactosylceramides` then your query would look like:
http://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search/resulttype=core&query=KW:galactosylceramides

Of course, you have to parse xml result, but I don't think it's a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example here, but not in Java. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/

Comment: I do not know if you noticed, but Renaud already posted a java example - from that same site ;)