# Accessing pubmed abstracts using Entrez Utilities Web Service

Tags: java, apache-axis, pubmed

I use [Entrez Utilities Web Service library](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/soap/v2.0/DOC/esoap_java_help.html) to access pubmed articles from my Java application (using pubmed identifier). Full working example how to use this tool was published by [Renaud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125617/renaud) in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410151/download-pubmed-abstracts-in-java) on [github](https://github.com/renaud/pubmed_ws_client). Everything works fine in most cases, however lately I found a pubmed id which makes the library crash.

The code that I use looks like this:

```
public PubmedArticleType searchById(Integer id) throws RemoteException {
    EUtilsServiceStub.ESearchRequest req = new EUtilsServiceStub.ESearchRequest();
    req.setDb("pubmed");
    req.setTerm(id+"[uid]");
    req.setEmail("gmail@gmail.com");
    req.setUsehistory("y");
    EUtilsServiceStub.ESearchResult res = service.run_eSearch(req);
    String webEnv = res.getWebEnv();
    String query_key = res.getQueryKey();

    EFetchPubmedServiceStub.EFetchRequest req2 = new EFetchPubmedServiceStub.EFetchRequest();
    req2.setWebEnv(webEnv);
    req2.setQuery_key(query_key);

    EFetchPubmedServiceStub.EFetchResult res2 = service2.run_eFetch(req2);
    for (int j = 0; j < res2.getPubmedArticleSet().getPubmedArticleSetChoice().length; j++) {

        PubmedArticleType art = res2.getPubmedArticleSet().getPubmedArticleSetChoice()[j].getPubmedArticle();
        if (art != null) {
            return art;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I call this function with `id = 22363258` I get the error that isn't informative at all:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EFetchPubmedServiceStub.fromOM(EFetchPubmedServiceStub.java)
    at gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EFetchPubmedServiceStub.run_eFetch(EFetchPubmedServiceStub.java:189)
    at ch.epfl.bbp.uima.pubmed.PubmedSearch.searchById(PubmedSearch.java:130)
    at ch.epfl.bbp.uima.pubmed.PubmedSearchTest.testPubmedId(PubmedSearchTest.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EFetchPubmedServiceStub$PubModel_type0$Factory.fromString(EFetchPubmedServiceStub.java:20118)
    at gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EFetchPubmedServiceStub$PubModel_type0$Factory.fromString(EFetchPubmedServiceStub.java:20129)
    at gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EFetchPubmedServiceStub$ArticleType$Factory.parse(EFetchPubmedServiceStub.java)
    at gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EFetchPubmedServiceStub$MedlineCitationType$Factory.parse(EFetchPubmedServiceStub.java:28780)
    at gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EFetchPubmedServiceStub$PubmedArticleType$Factory.parse(EFetchPubmedServiceStub.java:19147)
    at gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EFetchPubmedServiceStub$PubmedArticleSetChoiceE$Factory.parse(EFetchPubmedServiceStub.java)
    at gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EFetchPubmedServiceStub$PubmedArticleSet_type0$Factory.parse(EFetchPubmedServiceStub.java:56549)
    at gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.www.soap.eutils.EFetchPubmedServiceStub$EFetchResult$Factory.parse(EFetchPubmedServiceStub.java:50607)
    ... 27 more
```

So, I have two questions:

- What is the reason? What I can do to fix it?
- Is there any other java API that I could use to access pubmed abstracts? I know I can parse html pages, but I realy don't want to do it, because it introduces more problems than it solves...

Comment: I have also found this library - http://jeutils.sourceforge.net/ . I think this may be especially useful since the SOAP utility will be discontinued in July 2015 (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/mailman/pipermail/utilities-announce/2014-December.txt). However, the library seems to be a bit outdated and no longer updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://europepmc.org/RestfulWebService) is a RESTful API that allows to retrieve abstracts and all meta informations from pubmed db.

The exact link that would retrieve all the data that I needed looks like this: http://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search/resulttype=core&query=ext_id:22363258