# Spring RestTemplate works for String but not for my class

Tags: java, spring, spring-resttemplate

My problem is, if I call this URL and get a response with String, I got it, but with Class ESearchResult no. What I am doing here wrong? Please help...

```
 String url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=covid";//config.getPmcUrl() + "esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=covid";
    
    
    RestTemplate restTemplate = this.getRestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = this.getHeaders();
    
    HttpEntity<ESearchResult> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<ESearchResult>(headers);
    
    //ResponseEntity<ESearchResult> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, ESearchResult.class);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
    
    String  esearch = response.getBody(); //this works
    //ESearchResult  esearch = response.getBody();//this doesn't work
```

ESearchResult class I check with a namespace or without.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "eSearchResult", namespace = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20060628/esearch.dtd")
public class ESearchResult {
    
    /*@XmlElement(name = "IdList", namespace = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20060628/esearch.dtd")
    private List<IdList> idList;*/
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Count", namespace = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20060628/esearch.dtd")
    private Integer count;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "RetMax", namespace = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20060628/esearch.dtd")
    private Integer retMax;    

    @XmlElement(name = "RetStart", namespace = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20060628/esearch.dtd")
    private Integer retStart;
    
}
```

The result from URL

[image]

Comment: Can you share the error you received from this line
 
`ESearchResult  esearch = response.getBody();//this doesn't work`

Answer (score 2):

Add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Set your headers:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
```

and the this should work:

```
ResponseEntity<ESearchResult> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, ESearchResult.class);

ESearchResult esearch = response.getBody();
```

EDIT: consider that `RestTemplate` will be replaced by `Webclient`. You can setup a proper `WebClient` with the following:

```
WebClient wb = WebClient.builder()
            .defaultHeaders(header -> {
                header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
            })
            .exchangeStrategies(
                    ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                            .codecs(configurer -> {
                                configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Decoder(new Jaxb2XmlDecoder());
                                configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Encoder(new Jaxb2XmlEncoder());
                            })
                            .build()
            ).build();
```

And retrieve what you need with this:

```
ESearchResult  esearch = wb.get().uri("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=covid")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ESearchResult.class)
            .block();
```

The dependency that I added before will be still needed. Also, you need this one too:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This was helpful! is working, but I have attributes null...

Comment: Something is wrong... my error now is Could not unmarshal XML to class ESearchResult. With String works.

Comment: That's because the jackson-dataformat-xml is missing. Have you checked your dependencies? I've tried locally and it works.

Comment: Thank you! Is working, I just delete @XmlRootElement namespace in Class!